# SQL Case Statement with math in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
DECLARE @onlymonth bit
SET @onlymonth = 0

DECLARE @month int
SET @month = 5

SELECT 
SUM(amount) amount
FROM accounting ac
WHERE
DATEPART(mm,ac.date) <= @month
```

What I want is depending on the @onlymonth parameter remove the minor sign so... for example

...WHERE
    DATEPART(mm,ac.date) = CASE WHEN @onlymonth = 0 THEN = @month ELSE <= @month END...

Something like that.. any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions regarding checking for a month often result in a problem roughly a year later. Are you sure that you want to check for _any_ May and not May, 2013? If the latter then the query can use an index if you change the `WHERE` clause so that it does not need to perform a calculation on each row, e.g. `where @StartDate <= ac.date and ac.date <= @EndDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount) amount
FROM
    accounting ac
WHERE
    (DATEPART(mm,ac.date) = @month and @onlymonth = 0)
OR
    (DATEPART(mm,ac.date) <= @month and @onlymonth = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.

```
DECLARE @onlymonth bit
SET @onlymonth = 0

DECLARE @month int
SET @month = 5

if (@onlymonth = 0)
begin
    SELECT 
    SUM(amount) amount
    FROM accounting ac
    WHERE
    DATEPART(mm,ac.date) <= @month
end
else 
begin
    SELECT 
    SUM(amount) amount
    FROM accounting ac
    WHERE
    DATEPART(mm,ac.date) = @month
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

```
declare @month int, @bSingleMonth bit
set @month = 7
set @bSingleMonth = 1

SELECT SUM(amount) amount
FROM accounting ac
WHERE DATEPART(mm, ac.date)
     between 1 + IsNull(@bSingleMonth, 0) * (@month - 1) and @month
```

this makes it `between @month and @month` when `@bSingleMonth` is set and `between 1 and @month` when it is not.